# What does the "ship cost on star system" modifier do?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

At some places in the game I see a ship modifier of "ship cost on star system", for example the Vaulters' Ylona class (destroyer-equivalent) has an inherent attribute of "-5% ship cost on star system":

[image: ylona class ship description]

What does that modifier do? It sounds like a convoluted way of saying the ship is cheaper to produce, but I tried filling that hull with some modules and comparing it with another class without that attribute (Anjka class, corvette-equivalent) and it shows the same value listed under the ship's "cost".

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've read that right, in that it means the ship will be cheaper to produce. I think it's an effect of *building* the ship, that applies to the system that is building the ship, so it wouldn't show up on the build screen. It would just be built faster.